# Setting static IP on CentOS without system-config-network

Tags: centos, ip, static-ip

Background information:
I have a problem installing system-config-network. It appears it cannot find an update to sqlite (checks every mirror and comes back empty handed.) I have tried the skipping broken option and package cleanups from yum-utils.

Since I cannot get it installed, I decided to set an ip manually from console. A quick Google search comes back empty handed as for an easy how-to guide that works. What do I need to do for a currently configured DHCP ip to change it to a Static IP from console.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth[num]` file like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=<your MAC>
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=<ip>
GATEWAY=<gateway>
```

When you are done run `/etc/init.d/network restart`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the config files in /etc:  /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethx

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/ch-networkscripts.html